Find datasheet or similar model parts that can i replace with this: LTTH15L06DF
Need help to find out this datasheet or similar model parts that can i replace with this?
DIODE, Ultrafast, LTTH15L06DF, 600V, 15A, TO-220FPAC, LITEON Want LITEON Part datasheet for find similar part.
liteon technology corporation.
trouble to find datasheet of it.
using in my AC TO  DC POWER SUPPLY.

(When searching for a datasheet, try leaving out a letter suffix/all letters trailing the last digit.)

@user453869 Edit the original closed question, we didn't find data sheets for people. Par use the chat if you need help
